# grails javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'

Tags: reactjs, grails

i'm trying to run my app using this tutorial : 
http://guides.grails.org/building-a-react-app/guide/index.html

there is the the git repository
https://github.com/tetar998/building-a-react-app/tree/master/complete

but i m stuck with this error 
 Could not resolve view with name '/index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'

i am currently working with 
- groovy 2.4.11
- java 8u152
- grails 3.3.0

[image: there is a picture of my views folder]
and in there is my controller/demo/urlmappings

```
package demo

class UrlMappings {

static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }

    "/"(view: '/index')
    "500"(view: '/error')
    "404"(view: '/notFound')
}
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: does http://localhost:8080/vehicle work?

Comment: yes @Peter  localhost:8080/vehicle work